# Asynchronous function returning values then crashing on re-render

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a function `extractRatings` that takes data returned from a database call, `filteredVenue`, and filters through it:

```
const extractRatings = async () => {
  const foodRatings =  []
  const serviceRatings = []
  const valueRatings = []
  const atmosphereRatings = []
   filteredVenue.length>0 && filteredVenue[0].reviews.map((rating) => {
   foodRatings.push(rating.ratingFood)
   serviceRatings.push(rating.ratingService)
   valueRatings.push(rating.ratingValue)
   atmosphereRatings.push(rating.ratingAtmosphere)
  })
  return {foodRatings}
}

const {foodRating} = extractRatings()
```

It's working as it should, and when I console log the output `foodRating`, it returns the data I want.

The problem arises in the next step of processing the data. I have a function `getRating` which takes in the output of `extractRating` and performs various math stuff on it.

```
const getRating =  (rating) =>{
  const ratingInt =  rating.map((item) => parseInt(item))
  const ratingSum = ratingInt.reduce((x,y) => x+y)
  const ratingAve = Math.round(ratingSum/rating.length)
  return {ratingAve}
}

const food  = getRating(foodRating)
console.log(food) // no output
```

However, when I try to execute `getRating`, I get the following error in the browser:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')

I tried using `async/await` on the `getRatings` function, but it returned an unresolved promise.

```
const getRating = async (rating) =>{
  const ratingInt =  await rating.map((item) => parseInt(item))
  const ratingSum = await ratingInt.reduce((x,y) => x+y)
  const ratingAve = Math.round(ratingSum/rating.length)
  return {ratingAve}
}
```

I also tried putting conditionals in the same function, which didn't work:

```
const getRating =  (rating) =>{
  const ratingInt =  rating.length > 0 && rating && rating.map((item) => parseInt(item))
  const ratingSum = ratingInt.reduce((x,y) => x+y)
  const ratingAve = Math.round(ratingSum/rating.length)
  return {ratingAve}
}
```

So I'm confused about how to solve this - I can't tell if it's an async issue or if I need to be putting in more conditionals. Suggestions?

EDIT:

For context, here's the whole component:

```
import { useEffect,useState } from 'react'
import { convertToStars } from "../../helperFunctions";
import { getAverageRating } from '../../helperFunctions';

const MidSection = ({ filteredVenue }) => {

  const extractRatings = async () => {
    const foodRatings =  []
    const serviceRatings = []
    const valueRatings = []
    const atmosphereRatings = []
     filteredVenue.length>0 && filteredVenue[0].reviews.map((rating) => {
     foodRatings.push(rating.ratingFood)
     serviceRatings.push(rating.ratingService)
     valueRatings.push(rating.ratingValue)
     atmosphereRatings.push(rating.ratingAtmosphere)
    })
    return {foodRatings}
  }

  const {foodRating} = extractRatings()


  const getRating =  (rating) =>{
    const ratingInt =  rating.map((item) => parseInt(item))
    const ratingSum = ratingInt.reduce((x,y) => x+y)
    const ratingAve = Math.round(ratingSum/rating.length)
    return {ratingAve}
    }

    const food  = getRating(foodRating)
    console.log(food) // no output

  return (
    <div className="venue-page-mid">
      {filteredVenue.map((venue) => {
        return (
          <>
            <div className="venue-page-section left">
              <h2>Ratings and reviews</h2>
              <p>
                {venue.averageRating}
                {` `}
                {convertToStars(venue.averageRating)}
                {`  `}({`${venue.reviews.length} reviews`})
              </p>
              <div className="ratings">
                <h3>Ratings</h3>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div className="venue-page-section mid">
              <h2>Details</h2>
              <div className="details-container">
                <div className="details-item">
                  <h3>Cuisines</h3>
                  <p>Cafe</p>
                </div>
                <div className="details-item">
                  <h3>Special diets</h3>
                  <p>Vegetarian friendly, vegan options, gluten-free options</p>
                </div>
                <div className="details-item">
                  <h3>Meals</h3>
                  <p>Breakfast, Brunch, Lunch, After hours</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
};

export default MidSection;
```

Comment: Missing `await` on `const {foodRating} = extractRatings()`... Looks like `foodRating` is undefined.

Comment: 1. Don't use `async` / `await` just becuse something doesn't work. It won't solve it, but makes other things harder. 2. Don't return values wrapped in objects, unless you want to return multiple things. (Typo: `return {foodRatings}` vs `const {foodRating} = ...` makes it `undefined`!)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that extractRating is async (you see it in its signature  `const extractRatings = async () =>`)

To fix the problem,

- make it non async

```
const extractRatings = () => { // no async here

}
```

- or add an await when you use it (idem `const {foodRating} = await extractRatings()`)

The former should be preferred **if** you can

But if for some reason you want the latter (e.g you have simplified the problem), you may do it via a `useEffect`

```
const [foodRating, setFoodRating] = useState()
useEffect(() => {
  const doIt = async function () {
    // you now have the async function
    // which you could not before because it would be written on MidSection
    const extractRating = async () {///}
    const {...} = await extractRating()
    const getRating = (...)
    const foodRating = getRating(ratings)
    setFoodRating(foodRating) // use a setState
  }
  doIt()
}, [filteredValue])
```

Finally note that I would move the `extractRating` and `getRating` outside of the component so it stays simpler

```
const extractRating = xx
const getRating = xx
const MidSection = ({ filteredValue }) => {
  const [foodRating, setFoodRating] = useState()
  useEffect(() => {
    const doIt = function () {
      const {...} = await extractRating()
      const getRating = (...)
      setFoodRating(foodRating) // use a setState
    }
    doIt()
  })
}
```